# How to split a column of strings, and create rows from the separate elements?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm unable to split a text document into multiple sentences in a data frame and create rows for each sentence while other column values should be the same.
Let me explain it a little:

## Initially

```
A | B     | C | D
-------------
x | A.B   | x | x
y | C.D.E | y | y
```

### What I would like to have (after splitting text in B column)

```
A | B | C | D
-------------
x | A | x | x
x | B | x | x
y | C | y | y
y | D | y | y
y | E | y | y
```

### What I have done so far?

I've managed to split the text document into different sentences using split() method. Now I'm stuck on the second part.

Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Since you have managed to split the strings, they should now be lists. Just use `df = df.explode('B')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `str.split('.')` and `explode()`:

`str.split('.')` returns a list in preparation for explode. Explode requires list format in a column in order for that to work.

```
df['B'] = df['B'].str.split('.')
df
Out[10]: 
   A          B  C  D
0  x     [A, B]  x  x
1  y  [C, D, E]  y  y
```

Then explode the list, passing the column as a parameter, indicating that you want to explode the dataframe according to that column:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].str.split('.')
df = df.explode('B')
df
Out[11]: 
   A  B  C  D
0  x  A  x  x
0  x  B  x  x
1  y  C  y  y
1  y  D  y  y
1  y  E  y  y
```

Comment: You are amazing, man. Thank you so much. I'll accept the answer in a minute.